# Algorithm to convert an IEEE 754 double to a string?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, floating-point, ieee-754

Many programming languages that use IEEE 754 doubles provide a library function to convert those doubles to strings.  For example, C has `sprintf`, C++ has `stringstream`, Java has `Double.toString`, etc.

Internally, how are these functions implemented?  That is, what algorithm(s) are they using to convert the double into a string representation, given that they are often subject to programmer-chosen precision limitations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code used by various software environments to convert floating-point numbers to string representations is typically based on the following publications (the work by Steele and White is particularly frequently cited):

Jerome T. Coonen: "An Implementation Guide to a Proposed Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic." *Computer*, Vol. 13, No. 1, January 1980, pp. 68-79

Guy. L. Steele Jr. and J. L. White: "How to print floating-point numbers accurately". In proceedings of *ACM SIGPLAN '90 Conference on Programming Language Design and Implementation*, White Plains, New York, June 1990, pp. 112-126

David M. Gay: "Correctly rounded binary-decimal and decimal-binary conversions." Technical Report 90-10, AT&T Bell Laboratories, November 1990.

Some relevant followup work:

Robert G. Burger and R. Kent Dybvig: "Printing floating-point numbers quickly and accurately." In proceedings of *ACM SIGPLAN 1996 conference on Programming Language Design and Implementation*, Philadelphia, PA, USA, May 1996, pp. 108-116

Guy L. Steele Jr. and Jon L. White: "Retrospective: How to print floating-point numbers accurately." *ACM SIGPLAN Notices*, Vol. 39, No. 4, April 2004, pp. 372–389

Florian Loitsch: "Printing floating-point numbers quickly and accurately with integers." In proceedings of *2010 ACM SIGPLAN Conference on Programming Language Design and Implementation*, Toronto, ON, Canada, June 2010, pp. 233-243

Marc Andrysco, Ranjit Jhala, and Sorin Lerner: "Printing floating-point numbers: a faster, always correct method." *ACM SIGPLAN Notices*, Vol. 51, No. 1, January 2016, pp. 555-567

Ulf Adams: "Ryū: fast float-to-string conversion." *ACM SIGPLAN Notices*, Vol. 53, No. 4, April 2018, pp. 270-282

Comment: Another new paper in 2016: Andrysco, Marc, Ranjit Jhala, and Sorin Lerner. "Printing floating-point numbers: a faster, always correct method." ACM SIGPLAN Notices 51, no. 1 (2016): 555-567.

Comment: Another breakthrough with 3x performance over the older algorithms appeared in 2018:  "Ryū: fast float-to-string conversion" by Ulf Adams https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3192369

Comment: Thank you srm and sffc, I have added these latest publications to the answer.

Comment: I am building a benchmark of the different algorithms if anyone is interested to join. pm

Answer (score 16):

I believe you are looking for [Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.67.4438&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I found that link on another post: [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480790/exact-textual-representation-of-an-ieee-double)

Comment: A good suggestion IMO, but (sadly) that is rarely the algorithm chosen. Which is why 0.2999999999999999999566 and such regularly show up and cause much confusion.

Answer (score 6):

See Ryan Juckett's [**Printing Floating-Point Numbers**](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/printing-floating-point-numbers/) (2014), which describes history and implementations of floating-point to string conversions. In this four-part post, Ryan also provides a C++ implementation of Dragon4 based on [Steele and White (1990)](http://kurtstephens.com/files/p372-steele.pdf), which is an efficient algorithm to convert a binary number in floating point format to a decimal number in string format.

You can also see a C implementation of Ryan's Dragon4 for Numpy [**here**](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/dragon4.c), and use it within Python/Numpy 1.14 [`format_float_positional`](http://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html#numpy.format_float_positional) and [`format_float_scientific`](http://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html#numpy.format_float_scientific) functions.

---

In 2018, an algorithm/library [**Ryu**](https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu) was published, with bindings in many modern programming languages (C, Java, C++, C#, Scala, Rust, Julia, Go, ...)

Answer (score 3):

For most example languages you quote the source is freely consultable online as they're available in open source.

For Java, the class [java.lang.Double](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Double.java.html) delegates this work to [sun.misc.FloatingDecimal](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.html).  Check out its constructor and toJavaFormatString() method.

For C, glibc is always a good example, and there we [see](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdio-common/printf_fp.c;hb=HEAD) that floating point output is located in its own source file.