# Double 10 decimal Point Precision

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

We want to ensure that upto 10 decimal point values are kept while converting a double value to a  string.

When we tried %e or %f, it will not keep more than 5 decimal points. 
When we tried %.14f, the small values (less than 1.0e-20) are not properly converted to string.

What format string to be used to keep upto 10 decimal points for double values?

Comment: Have you tried `%.10g` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228438/convert-double-float-to-string , can be useful for you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `%.17g` to print with the most appropriate format for the double in question.

```
printf("%.17g\n", 10000.);
printf("%.17g\n", 240.0008);
printf("%.17g\n", 0.0000000013);

10000
240.0008
1.3000000000000001e-009
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you *do* know that the `float` type (single-precision floating point) only ever *keeps* six decimal digits of precision? No conversion specifier can give precision that isn't there to begin with... (The `double` type keeps about 15 digits of precision, FYI.)

Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation

**Update:** JasonD has the answer to your updated question. Keeping this up for posteriority.

Comment: I am looking for double value conversion. Updated y post

Answer (score 1):

Float can store this number of decimal only if the number is small, otherwise use double.

In this example `%.17g` and  `%.14f` are working without problem :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        double v = 0.12345678912345;
        printf("%.17g   %.14f  \n", v, v);
        return 0;
}
```

Displayed result :

```
0.12345678912345   0.12345678912345
```

From the documentation

> **f** : Decimal floating point, lowercase 392.65
>
> **e** : Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), lowercase    3.9265e+2
>
> **g** : Use the shortest representation: %e or %f 392.65

So using `%.14f` it is fine

Edit:

> the small values (less than 1.0e-20) are not properly converted to string.

To display more than 20 decimal, you should use long double... But if you only need to store 1.0e-20 and do not need to print more than 6 decimal, float can hold it.

For long double, you need to use something like `%.21Lg`. For example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        long double v = 0.123456789123456789123456789;
        printf("%.21Lg   %.21Lf   \n", v, v);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't need `long double` to hold / display 1.0e-20. Even a simple `float` can hold values as small as 1.0e-37 (`FLT_MIN`)...

Comment: Indeed, if the value is small a simple float can hold it... I am going to fix it