# Converting `double` to `string`

Tags: c++, string, double, type-conversion

I am implementing this:

```
double x;
ostringstream x_convert;
x_convert << x;
string x_str = x_convert.str();
```

It seems a bit superfluous. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228438/convert-double-float-to-string

Comment: Don't tag this question `[C]`.  `ostringstream`, `.str();`, are `[C++]` only, not `[C]`

Comment: You could just wrap the whole thing in a function so you do less typing. C++11 did this for you, `std::to_string()`, as everyone pointed out. The problem is lack of control on how the string looks like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using C++11? If so, there's:

```
auto x_str = std::to_string(x);
```

Answer (score 4):

**[`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)**:

```
std::string x_str = std::to_string(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have is the *safest* method (pre-C++11).

Alternatively, you could so something like:

```
double value = SOME_VALUE;
char buffer[100] = {};
sprintf(buffer, "%f", value);
std::string s = buffer;
```

Which is functionally equivalent to what `std::to_string` does.  You must be careful to have enough space allocated for `buffer`, and (as you can see), you are still writing about 4 lines of code to do this conversion, so it is no more (nor less) elegant than the other methods.

If you are stuck in pre-C++11, you can implement your own `to_string` by doing something like:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(T t)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << t;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Which will work for any type that already has an overload for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T&)`.

Comment: Um, there's nothing in this use of `sprintf` that is not "safe"; it will work just fine.

Comment: @PeteBecker As I've allocated a buffer that is substantially larger than a floating point precision can be in this case, you are correct.  If I change the size of `buffer` to 10, for example, it is no longer the case.

Comment: Yes, if the code was different, the result could be different. But it's not, and the statement that it "is not safe as written" is wrong.

Comment: Just take out the parenthetical. There's no need to take cheap shots at `sprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

Without C++11 you may write your own `to_string` function:

```
string to_string(double x) {
  ostringstream x_convert;
  x_convert << x;
  return x_convert.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, as mentioned by others, use `std::to_string`.

Without C++11, you are stuck with the code you've already written, or something along those lines.  You can make the use of that code a bit more elegant (read: less typing) by constructing a device which does the string building for you:

```
class StringBuilder
{
public:
    template <typename T> inline StringBuilder& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        mStream << t;
        return * this;
    }
    inline std::string get() const
    {
        return mStream.str();
    }
    inline operator std::string () const
    {
        return get();
    }
private:
    std::stringstream mStream;
};
```

Now you can:

```
double x;
string x_str = StringBuilder() << x;
```

But at the end of the day it's really just syntactic sugar for the same thing.  There are similar devices in Boost -- I'd use those if you can.