# Convert a double to char* with cython

Tags: c, char, cython

In Cython, how can I convert produce a C string (`char *`) representation of a C double without using Python objects (e.g. `bytes` or `str`) as an intermediate?

In fact, I have defined my function in a C-extension file (.pyx) as follows:

```
cdef void function(self, char* var1) nogil:

    cdef char* chaine =""
    cdef double inter = 0.0
    #Here there is some treatment which modifies the value of the local variable 'inter' so that it contains a double value different from 0
    strcat(chaine ,  "(")
    strcat(chaine , <char*>inter)
    strcat(chaine ,  ")**beta")

    strcpy(&var1,  chaine)
```

After compilation of the file, I have the errors `C2440 : impossible de convertir de 'double' en 'char*'` and `C2168 : strcat nombre de paramètres de fonction intrinséque insuffisant`

How can I fix the problem please?

Comment: Please read [ask] and the [help], try to provide a [mcve] and explain why your code doesn't work. If you have no code, there is little to no chance that you will get help from this site.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. You need to avoid doing this in [tag:c] or learn exactly what are c strings and how they work.

Comment: I tried to simplify the defenition of the function because it is more complicated in the real code, there is a lot of treatment inside.

Comment: It doesn't matter. There is a fundamental error with the code that stems from a lack of knowledge about c strings and memory management.

Comment: Sorry, I am really a beginner in coding cython code :/

Comment: @koukou I suspect that you'd be _much_ better doing this in Python. This doesn't look like code that should be rate-limiting, so Python strings are probably preferable to using C. (And if you just want to make a `nogil` function, then why? You probably don't need to...)

Comment: In fact, the example of this function is taken from the source code of a package from Anaconda/scikit-learn. I am just fitting this code to my contribution. So, the added code should respect the structure already presented.

Comment: You can use a small `with gil:` block and put some Python code there. There might be a small speed cost, but you'll probably find it a lot easier.

Comment: In addition to the good comments above, you could have a look at `stdio.snprintf`, for a concrete example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835220/4121573

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the issue of whether or not it even is worth doing this at the python or C level, it looks like there are several critical misunderstandings at the C level presented in your sample code. There is a lot of cover, so I will just give few pointers to help steer you in the right direction; feel free to post a corrected version of your code as an answer once you feel more comfortable with C and cython.

First, a word about pointers. A pointer is just a variable that holds a memory address. This memory address "points" to some contents in memory. Here is a simple sample that might clear this up:

```
cdef int a_number = 42#just a regular int, nothing special here :)
cdef int* a_pointer = &a_number#"referencing" to get the address of a_number
cdef int b_number = a_pointer[0]#"dereferencing" to get the value at a_pointer
#note the dereferencing syntax is different in cython than in C!!!
```

Second is how functions work. In C, everything is **pass-by-value**. This means that whenever you pass parameters to a function, a **copy** of the parameter is made and operations take place on this copy. This includes pointers; if you try to set your `var1` pointer like you are attempting in `function`, the actual `var1` pointer is unchanged and only a local copy within the scope of `function` is being modified. Clearly not what we want!

Third, we need to see how strings are represented in C. Strings are basically a list of characters that you care about, followed by a null terminator `\0`. I am sure there are lots of sources you can read online about the difference between say `char*` and `char[]`, and I strongly suggest you take a look at them. I will just say here that `char*` is just a pointer, and so it only points to the first character. `char*` also has no concept of the length of the string.

Once you have a good handle of all of these concepts, you can then start looking at functions on the linux man pages like [strcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) and [strcat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html). I would also look up [sprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), which is sort of similar to python's `format` and might be smarter than concatenating a bunch of pieces together. Hope this helps you on your learning journey, and good luck!

Comment: Yees, this is setting me on the right track. Thank you