# Floating point determinism - Java makes wrong output, C++ correct

Tags: java, c++, floating-point, interpolation, precision

I'm facing a huge problem and I have no idea what's causing it and how to fix this. I'm creating a game where I draw objects in Java. For drawing I use linear interpolation which uses 'alpha' value to move the object with a specific time value in one frame.

Here is how the interpolation algorithm looks like:

```
draw.x = current.getX() * alpha + previous.getX() * (1.0f - alpha);
```

All of the above values are floats (alpha, current, prev and draw).

Let's assume, that we're not moving and our `current.getX()` and `previous.getX()` are `100.0f` floats.

Alpha value is random (it's not random, but it's a number in `0.0` - `1.0` range) - also float.

Let's take `alpha = 0,4352343`

```
draw.x = 100.f * 0.4352343 + 100.f * (1.0f - 0.4352343) == 43,52343 + 56,47657 == 100
```

which is perfect, cause we're not moving - it should be 100 (our previous and current positions are both 100).

This is how math works, no matter what value `alpha` would be - it will always return `100`, right?

**NO!**

In C++ it does - it works perfectly, I have tested it for 30 minutes with an output of 10 million cases - it always returns `100.0`.

But in Java - it doesn't. For 80.000 cases there are ~400-500 cases where `draw.x` (return value from our function) becomes 99.99999999999.

It's completly unacceptable cause when I draw, I need to use `int`, so I have to cast, so it gives 99 value and you can guess what happens with the animation.

I have just one question - how is this possible, that above algorithm can give different values in Java and C++ and how to fix this in Java?

Comment: Why on earth would you cast it instead of rounding?

Comment: With C++ is important what concrete implementation do You use. Some may compute like this, some different

Comment: Did you compare the binary IEEE754 representations  in both cases? I assume they are the same, and that the runtime libraries just use different algorithms to convert the float to string, so that you get different **outputs**. See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153979/algorithm-to-convert-an-ieee-754-double-to-a-string

Comment: One needs to understand floating-point arithmetic to be a programmer. It is not exact. The expectation that it be exact betrays that one does not understand floating-point arithmetic. Learn about it if you wish to be a programmer.
Study this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with rounding errors, although I'm uncertain why they come about. To fix it, you can use

right answer =Math.round(answer);