# How To Get Digits Past Decimal In Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This is how I'm doing it in Python... Is there a more elegant way to do it in Elixir?

```
def get_digits_past_decimal(number):
    number_string = str(number)
    dig_past_decimal = abs(Decimal(number_string).as_tuple().exponent)
    return dig_past_decimal
```

Comment: Is this accurate enough for your needs: `123.456 |> Float.to_string |> String.split(".") |> Enum.at(1) |> byte_size`?

Comment: That works great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd convert the float to a string and count the number of bytes after the dot:

One Liner:

```
float |> Float.to_string |> String.split(".") |> Enum.at(1) |> byte_size
```

Slightly longer but more efficient as it doesn't create an intermediary list:

```
string = float |> Float.to_string
{start, _} = :binary.match(string, ".")
byte_size(string) - start - 1
```

Test:

```
defmodule A do
  def count1(float) do
    float |> Float.to_string |> String.split(".") |> Enum.at(1) |> byte_size
  end

  def count2(float) do
    string = float |> Float.to_string
    {start, _} = :binary.match(string, ".")
    byte_size(string) - start - 1
  end
end

for f <- [0.1, 0.234, 123.456, 0.0000000001] do
  IO.inspect {A.count1(f), A.count2(f)}
end
```

Output:

```
{1, 1}
{3, 3}
{3, 3}
{5, 5}
```

Note: the results may not be identical to Python since there are multiple ways to convert a float to a decimal string with slightly different outputs and tradeoffs. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153979/algorithm-to-convert-an-ieee-754-double-to-a-string) has some more information about this.