# Inconsistent printing of floats. Why DOES it work sometimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Using following (near minimal) example:

```
import numpy as np
for x in np.arange(0,2,0.1):
    print(x)
```

We get:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9
1.0
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3
1.4000000000000001
1.5
1.6
1.7000000000000002
1.8
1.9000000000000001
```

as output.

I get that 'floating numbers precision issues' are to blame for the X.X000001 outputs but what I don't understand is how come it sometimes DOES work. Clearly 0.3 cannot be represented precisely in base 2 by a float and I fail to see any pattern in the numbers that didn't display with just one decimal digit.

How come Python knows that 0.1 is sufficient to display a number? What kind of magic tells it to truncate the remaining digits? Why does it work only sometimes?

Comment: Relevant: [Algorithm to convert an IEEE 754 double to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153979/algorithm-to-convert-an-ieee-754-double-to-a-string)

Comment: Check `print(format(x, '.30f'))` and see that `0.1` has one more zero in its inaccurate float representation. What happens is that the default truncation limit seems to include 16 decimal digits, but the next nonzero is at 17th in cases where you see an "exact" value in the output. I couldn't quickly find this figure in the documentation, it might easily be an implemnetation detail. You shouldn't make anything important depend on the automatic formatting of floats after all. If you need to rely on this, print/round yourself, or even better, check _approximate_ equality of floats.

Comment: Found a hint in [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html): "_Historically, the Python prompt and built-in repr() function would choose the one with 17 significant digits, 0.10000000000000001. Starting with Python 3.1, Python (on most systems) is now able to choose the shortest of these and simply display 0.1._". This sounds a lot like an implementation detail.

Comment: @AndrasDeak So it stops printing at first zero digit after decimal point? This can't possibly be right...

Comment: For anyone looking at this with the Python `float` type, take into account that `numpy` has its own `float` types that are being printed here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: @AndrasDeak So if it finds two possible representations it picks shorter one? It doesn't explain why it works sometimes and sometimes not...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I noticed that but doing the above tests with `x` vs `float(x)` gives the same results. Numpy scalars might be printed differently (i.e. just like native floats).

Comment: I've reopened this because as it turns out there is no canonical question on *Numpy*'s floating point formatting that I could find.

Comment: @Radost "So it stops printing at first zero digit after decimal point?" More like, don't print trailing zeros after truncating to 16 (or however many) digits.

Comment: @chepner it's more complicated than that, `0.3` and `0.4` share the same number of zeros in their decimal representation yet they are printed differently. The reason is the uniqueness criterion of the `dtoa` algorithm that Martijn mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are printing `numpy.float64` objects, not the Python built-in `float` type, which uses [David Gay's dtoa algorithm](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9776b0636ae39668d3ce1c006d4be01dad01bf9f/Python/dtoa.c#L2204-L2845).

As of [version 1.14](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/release.html#float-printing-now-uses-dragon4-algorithm-for-shortest-decimal-representation), numpy uses the [dragon4 algorithm to print floating point values](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9941), tuned to approach the same output as the David Gay algorithm used for the Python `float` type:

> Numpy scalars use the dragon4 algorithm in "unique" mode (see below) for str/repr, in a way that tries to match python float output.

The [`numpy.format_float_positional()` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html#numpy.format_float_positional) documents this in a bit more detail:

> `unique` : boolean, optional
>
> If `True`, use a digit-generation strategy which gives the shortest representation which uniquely identifies the floating-point number from other values of the same type, by judicious rounding. If precision was omitted, print out all necessary digits, otherwise digit generation is cut off after precision digits and the remaining value is rounded.

So `0.2` can uniquely be presented by only printing `0.2`, but the next value in the series (`0.30000000000000004`) can't, you *have* to include the extra digits to uniquely represent the exact value.

The *how* of this is actually quite involved; you can read a full report on this in Bungie's *Destiny* gameplay engineer Ryan Juckett's [*Printing Floating-Point Numbers* series](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/printing-floating-point-numbers/).

But basically the code outputting the string needs to determine what shortest representation exists for all decimal numbers clustering around the possible floating point number that can't be interpreted as the next or preceding possible floating point number:

> [image: floating point number line for 0.1, with the next and previous possible float values and possible representations]

This image comes from [*The Shortest Decimal String That Round-Trips: Examples*](https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-shortest-decimal-string-that-round-trips-examples/) by [Rick Regan](https://www.exploringbinary.com/about/), which covers some other cases as well. Numbers in *blue* are possible `float64` values, in *green* are possible representations of decimal numbers. Note the grey half-way point markers, any representation that fits between those two half-way points around a float value are fair game, as all of those representations would produce the same value.

The goal of both the David Gay and Dragon4 algorithms is to find the shortest decimal string output that would produce the exact same float value again. From the [Python 3.1 *What's New* section on the David Gay approach](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes):

> Python now uses David Gay’s algorithm for finding the shortest floating point representation that doesn’t change its value. This should help mitigate some of the confusion surrounding binary floating point numbers.
>
> The significance is easily seen with a number like `1.1` which does not have an exact equivalent in binary floating point. Since there is no exact equivalent, an expression like `float('1.1')` evaluates to the nearest representable value which is `0x1.199999999999ap+0` in hex or `1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625` in decimal. That nearest value was and still is used in subsequent floating point calculations.
>
> What is new is how the number gets displayed. Formerly, Python used a simple approach. The value of `repr(1.1)` was computed as `format(1.1, '.17g')` which evaluated to `'1.1000000000000001'`. The advantage of using 17 digits was that it relied on IEEE-754 guarantees to assure that `eval(repr(1.1))` would round-trip exactly to its original value. The disadvantage is that many people found the output to be confusing (mistaking intrinsic limitations of binary floating point
>   representation as being a problem with Python itself).
>
> The new algorithm for `repr(1.1)` is smarter and returns `'1.1'`. Effectively, it searches all equivalent string representations (ones that get stored with the same underlying float value) and returns the shortest representation.
>
> The new algorithm tends to emit cleaner representations when possible, but it does not change the underlying values. So, it is still the case that `1.1 + 2.2 != 3.3` even though the representations may suggest otherwise.

Comment: I'd emphasize more what the native python behaviour is, because I think numpy in the question is a red herring. OP could've gotten the same output and the same questions with `for x in range(21): print(x*0.1)`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: we can cover that too, but the differences between David Gay's and Dragon4 are so academical and my head so flu-ridden today that I probably have to leave that for now. And I think there is already another post here on SO that covers the Python `float` type angle already.

Comment: Oh, hope you get well soon! If you end up finding that native float formatting post it would be worth linking it here at least in comments; I couldn't find it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: there is [Unexpected floating-point representations in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/11242062), there may be more.