# Python numpy:How many digits does np.float64 have?

Tags: numpy, floating-point

So I'm doing taylor expansion for exp(11.2). When I print all terms, I find some terms have 15 digits but some have 17 digits. I wonder why is that happening?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format : "The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision (2−53 ≈ 1.11 × 10−16)."  I think, but am not sure, that the exact precision depends on the number's value, hence the 15-17 decimal place variation.  If you find this sort of thing interesting, check out Bruce Dawson's blog, https://randomascii.wordpress.com/

Comment: Assuming that your coefficients are NumPy `np.float64` objects, it's because NumPy (since version 1.14.0) prints the shortest decimal representation that converts back to the original float under normal round-ties-to-even rounding. See release notes here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.14.0-notes.html#many-changes-to-array-printing-disableable-with-the-new-legacy-printing-mode. It can be shown that (assuming IEEE 754 binary64 format), 17 digits are always enough to recover the value exactly, but sometimes you can get away with fewer.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55727933/270986

Comment: It has [53 significant _binary_ digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).  That manifests itself as 15 to 17 _decimal_ digits.  When printing, best to print to 17 significant digits to distinguish possible results.