# While incrementing by 0.1 in the following python3 tkinter code I am getting continuous 0000000 or 99999999 after some mouse scroll?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count

    if event.delta == -120:
        count -= float(0.1)
    elif event.delta == 120:
        count += float(0.1)
    label["text"] = count


count = float(0)
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("turn mouse wheel")
root["bg"] = "darkgreen"


root.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)


label = tk.Label(root, font=("courier", 18, "bold"), width=10)
label.pack(padx=40, pady=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Expecting to see count value smoothly increase or decrease by 0.1 at every up/down mousewheel scroll but getting continuous 0000000 and 99999999 after few mousewheel scrolls, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count

    if event.delta == -120:
        count -= float(0.1)
    elif event.delta == 120:
        count += float(0.1)
    label["text"] = str(round(count, 1)) # changed your code here


count = float(0)
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("turn mouse wheel")
root["bg"] = "darkgreen"


root.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)


label = tk.Label(root, font=("courier", 18, "bold"), width=10)
label.pack(padx=40, pady=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Your issue is with floating point inaccuracy. Sometimes, adding, multiplying, etc. floating point numbers can cause strange behavior. To learn why, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

When I was printing out the result of "count" sometimes the values would look like `0.8999999999999999` which I believe was giving the tkinter library grief.

This fixes your problem by forcing your program to round to one decimal place.

Comment: No need to convert to str here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, as @JRose stated, in floating-point accuracy.

You can avoid the floating point rounding issues by using [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module.

Example (note, I slightly modified your example to make it run on linux):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from decimal import Decimal


def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count

    if event.num == 4:
        count -= Decimal("0.1")
    else:
        count += Decimal("0.1")
    label["text"] = count


count = Decimal("0")
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("turn mouse wheel")
root["bg"] = "darkgreen"


root.bind("<Button-4>", mouse_wheel)
root.bind("<Button-5>", mouse_wheel)


label = tk.Label(root, font=("courier", 18, "bold"), width=10)
label.pack(padx=40, pady=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Creates this application:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By Referring to this you can see why float is behaving inconsistent
https://stackoverflow[.com/questions/55727214/inconsistent-printing-of-floats-why-does-it-work-sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727214/inconsistent-printing-of-floats-why-does-it-work-sometimes)

you can try the following...

```
import tkinter as tk


def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count

    print(event.delta)

    if event.delta == -120:
        count -= 0.1
    elif event.delta == 120:
        count += 0.1
    label["text"] = round(count, 1)


count = 0.0
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("turn mouse wheel")
root["bg"] = "darkgreen"


root.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)


label = tk.Label(root, font=("courier", 18, "bold"), width=10)
label.pack(padx=40, pady=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is in the way you have used `event.delta`. You can replace your **mouse_wheel** function with the following code:

```
def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count

    if event.delta < 0:
        count -= 0.1
    elif event.delta > 0:
        count += 0.1
    label["text"] = count
```

In this code, we adjust the increment and decrement values to 0.1 (instead of using float(0.1)) and adjust the conditions for scrolling up (event.delta > 0) and down (event.delta < 0). This should result in a smoother increase or decrease of the count value when scrolling the mouse wheel.

Comment: It does not solve OP issue which is about floating point accuracy mentioned in other answers.